# Keycloak cluster Production setup on Kubernetes - Google K8S Engine (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, google-kubernetes-engine, keycloak-services

I am trying to deploy Keycloak onto Kubernetes Engine in HA (cluster) mode.
I am doing the deployment with an ingress service with TLS setting to be able to access externally.

The TLS setting was pretty straightforward, so got it done.

I placed the manifest files here
https://github.com/vsomasvr/keycloak-gke/tree/master/keycloak

The issue is that the keycloak does not form the cluster, hence keycloak is not functioning, the authentication itself fails.
This manifest works well for a single replica (which is not a cluster, so not helpful and not interested in sticky-session related config).

I think this is the crucial problem to be solved for the keycloak production installtion.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak ?

Comment: @RyanDawson Yes, I have. I was facing issue with cluster formation. I provided the feedback in the comments here https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/8355#issuecomment-429594852

Comment: I guess you need to use 4.5.0.Final? I'm wondering whether you could use a previous version of the chart to get a previous version of keycloak as sfitts mentions there.

Comment: @RyanDawson Thank you for the suggestion. I had tried the old version, strangely the ingress service is failing there (I couldn't figure out the cause, it just says healthy instances =0). Added more details here https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/8355#issuecomment-430446063

Comment: I got the previous version working with nginx ingress service (thanks to sfitts for the suggestions) as described in detail in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blogpost on this [here](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/04/keycloak-cluster-setup.html).

The only things I needed to do where the following:

**1) Create own Docker image**

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest

ADD cli/JDBC_PING.cli /opt/jboss/tools/cli/jgroups/discovery/
```

The `JDBC_PING.cli` can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fit2anything/keycloak-cluster-setup-and-configuration/master/src/JDBC_PING.cli)

**2) Update your deployment with an extra Env**

```
- name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
  value: "JDBC_PING"
```

This did the job for me with 2 replicas on GKE.

Comment: I just tried and it did not work, can you post your full config? Did you use the codecentric helm chart? https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak